# user_signed_in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I 'm pretty new to Ruby on Rails. I'm only a bit familiar with devise and the rails/ruby methods.

I have a sign in page. I have a page that checks if the user is signed in; if he is, one partial is displayed, if not, another partial is displayed;

```
<%= render(user_signed_in? ? '/layouts/signed_in_header' : '/layouts/signed_out_header') %>
```

Now, how can I have the above, with just one html.erb exception? Is there something like an Is_not method?

I don't want the signed_in_header to be displayed if the user is logged in AND the page he is on is, say, not_here_please. It should display on every other page, if the user is signed in.

Is there something like:

```
<%= render(user_signed_in? ? and page_is_not 'not_here_please'
'/layouts/signed_in_header' : '/layouts/signed_out_header') %>
```

Thanks for any help,

Chris.

Comment: you probably want to construct it like this `render( (bool_expr1 and bool_expr2) ? 'sign_in' : 'sign_out')`.

Answer (score 1):

As maksimov said :

```
<%= render((user_signed_in? && controller.action_name != 'not_here_please') ? '/layouts/signed_in_header' : '/layouts/signed_out_header') %>
```

Feel free to use anything different from `controller.action_name` in your condition. I just figured it was the most appropriate way to represent what you asked for.

Comment: Cool Sparda and maksimov, I'll check it out.

Comment: Hi. In my controllers folder, I have a controller called home_controller. In the homecontroller.rb I have a method called 'map'. it goes: 'def map (next line) end' In my view folder I have map.html.erb, so I presumed logically it's the view related to that ,map' method in the controller. But my code, which you suggested, '<#%= render((user_signed_in? && home_controller.map  != 'map') ? '/layouts/signed_in_header' : '/layouts/signed_out_header') %>
gives me an error: undefined local variable or method `home_controller' for #<#<etc.. Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks

Comment: Ok let me correct that : `controller.action_name` has to stay **controller.action_name** like I wrote it, this returns the current action. So based on that, your condition would be `controller.action_name != 'map'`. (basically I'm trying to say that `controller.action_name` has to stay written like this)